# Java sum of EvenNumbers

Tags: java, sum

It counts up to 5 and sum of 5 even numbers. I did it but it didn't work correctly(Mistake is about calculating the sum).Can you look at it ?

Here the code:

```
package com.java.ornekler;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            isEven(n);
            if (!isEven(n)) {
                n++;
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println(+n + " is a even number ");
                 n++;
                sum = sum + n;
                count++;
                if (count == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Sum is : " +sum);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        while (n <= 10);
    }


    public static boolean isEven(int n) {
        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
2 is a even number 
4 is a even number 
6 is a even number 
8 is a even number 
10 is a even number 
Sum is : 35
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: But you *increment `n`* before you *add* it to `sum`...

Comment: You're incrementing `n` before adding it to the sum. Do that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
n++;
sum = sum + n; // here you incremented n then added to sum.
```

change to

```
sum = sum + n;
n++;
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your sum is at 35 is because you increment your `n` one more time before you sum it together. Your total is `30` + `numberOfN` = `35`

Your else statement should look like this

```
 else {
    System.out.println(+n + " is a even number ");
    sum = sum + n;
    n++; // this was above and should be here
    count++;
    if (count == 5) {
        System.out.println("Sum is : " +sum);
        break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find an odd number, you do this:

```
System.out.println(+n + " is a even number ");
n++;
sum = sum + n;
```

So, if `n==4`, first you bump it up so that `n==5`. *Then* you add it to `sum`, so `sum` increases by 5, not 4.

So fix this, add to `sum` *before* incrementing `n`.

More generally, instead of jumping up in ones, testing for even-ness, why not start on an even number, and jump up in twos?

And, rather than having a `println` and a `break` in an `if` within the loop, make it an exit condition of the loop, and put the `println` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Along with comments above and you have duplicity statement: `n++;`.
Put that statement after if{}else{} block.

Revise the code as follows:

```
   do {
        isEven(n);
        if (!isEven(n)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println(+n + " is a even number ");
            sum = sum + n;
            count++;
            if (count == 5) {
                System.out.println("Sum is : " +sum);
                break;
            }
        }
        n++;

    }

    while (n <= 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 syntax might be easier to follow using predefined functions for summing and limiting

```
package test.test;

import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sum = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(10).filter(isEven()).peek(Snippet::printEvenNumber).sum();
        System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);

    }

    private static void printEvenNumber(int i) {
        System.out.println(i + " is an even number");
    }

    private static IntPredicate isEven() {
        return i -> i % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```